# How to make turtle stop from going off screen

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a simple game and right now I am trying to keep the turtle from going off the screen. I added a function in my class to stop it but it doesn't work. I don't know why. Also, when I try to print turtle.xcor(), I get it's memory location instead of it's xcords, how to I fix that as well. Thanks a lot! Code:

```
class Player(Turtle):
def __init__(self, speed=1):
    Turtle.__init__(self, shape='turtle')

    self.speed = speed
    self.color(color)
    self.hideturtle()
    self.turtlesize(2)
    self.setheading(90)
    self.penup()
    self.backward(180)
    self.showturtle()

    self.move()
    self.wall_checker()

def move(self):
    self.forward(self.speed)
    screen.ontimer(self.move)

def turn_left(self):
    self.left(10)

def turn_right(self):
    self.right(10)

def accelerate(self):
    self.speed += 1

def deaccelerate(self):
    self.speed -= 1
    if self.speed < 1:
        self.speed = 1

def wall_checker(self):
    if self.xcor() > 800:
        self.goto(790, self.ycor())

    elif self.xcor() < -800:
        self.goto(-790, self.ycor())

    elif self.ycor() > 800:
        self.goto(self.xcor(), 790)

    elif self.ycor() < -800:
        self.goto(self.xcor(), -790)
```

Comment: `turtle` is nice for drawing figures but for games are better modules - like `pygame` `pgzero` (`pygame zero`), `Arcade`,

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see which function should stop it.And I don't see where you print `turtle.xcor()` - maybe you forgot `()` and it shows function's position

Comment: as for me in `move` you should check position after `forward` and if it outside screen then run `backward` and stop or change direction `left/right`

Comment: as for me you should run `wall_checker` inside `move` after `forward`

Comment: in wall_checker you should rather separatelly check `xcor` and separatelly check `ycor`. you may have both values outside screen but your code top checking `ycor` when `xcor` outside screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run `wall_check()` inside `move()` after `forward()`

```
    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.speed)
        self.wall_checker()
        screen.ontimer(self.move)
```

that's all.

---

Minimal working code.

On my computer I had to use smaller values in `wall_checker` to check `xcor()`, `ycor()` - maybe I have smaller screen.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Player(Turtle):
    
    def __init__(self, speed=1, color='red'):
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape='turtle')
    
        self.speed = speed
        self.color(color)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.turtlesize(2)
        self.setheading(90)
        self.penup()
        self.backward(180)
        self.showturtle()
    
        self.move()
    
    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.speed)
        self.wall_checker()
        screen.ontimer(self.move)
    
    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(10)
    
    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(10)
    
    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 1
    
    def deaccelerate(self):
        self.speed -= 1
        if self.speed < 1:
            self.speed = 1
    
    def wall_checker(self):
        #print(self.xcor(), self.ycor())
        
        if self.xcor() > 300:
            self.goto(290, self.ycor())
        elif self.xcor() < -300:
            self.goto(-290, self.ycor())
    
        if self.ycor() > 300:
            self.goto(self.xcor(), 290)
        elif self.ycor() < -300:
            self.goto(self.xcor(), -290)

screen = Screen()
player = Player(speed=10)
```

---

**BTW:**

This code has other problem. It moves and displays in new place, next it checks position, and next it moves back - so turtle in blinking (you see it in both places).

In modules for games you could first calculate new position without displaying in new place, check if it is outside screen and use old values, and finally it would display it in only one place.

In `turtle` you could use `screen.tracer(False)` to stop automatic update turtle on screen and later use `screen.update()` after all moves but it doesn't work as I expected with `goto` - but it works with `backward()` to move back in old place

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Player(Turtle):
    
    def __init__(self, speed=1, color='red'):
        Turtle.__init__(self, shape='turtle')
    
        self.speed = speed
        self.color(color)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.turtlesize(2)
        self.setheading(90)
        self.penup()
        self.backward(180)
        self.showturtle()
    
        self.move()
    
    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.speed)
        self.wall_checker()
        screen.update()  # update screen
        screen.ontimer(self.move)
    
    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(10)
    
    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(10)
    
    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 1
    
    def deaccelerate(self):
        self.speed -= 1
        if self.speed < 1:
            self.speed = 1
    
    def wall_checker(self):
        #print(self.xcor(), self.ycor())
        
        while self.xcor() > 300:
            self.backward(1)
            
        while self.xcor() < -300:
            self.backward(1)
    
        while self.ycor() > 300:
            self.backward(1)
            
        while self.ycor() < -300:
            self.backward(1)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)  # don't update screen automatically

player = Player(speed=10)
```

---

Frankly, `turtle` is nice for drawing figures (see [gallery](https://blog.furas.pl/rysowanie-w-turtle-galeria-rysunkow.html))
but for games there are better modules - ie. [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/), [pygame zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [arcade](https://api.arcade.academy/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

you should start by setting a screen boundary and then work out an if statement something like:

```
from turtle import Screen
from turtle import Turtle
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
turtle = Turtle()
if turtle.xcor() == 300 or turtle.xcor() == -300:
    turtle.left(180) #to turn back on x-axis#
```

Answer (score -2):

I made a simple code try this.

```
import turtle

fred=turtle.Turtle()

#setting variables
run = True
speed = 1

#drawing straight Line
fred.lt(90)
fred.up()
fred.fd(100)
fred.down()
fred.rt(180)
fred.fd(200)

#re-position turtle fred
fred.up()
fred.setpos(-100,0)
fred.lt(90)
while(run):
  fred.setpos(fred.xcor() + speed,fred.ycor())
  
  #making turtle to stop after hitting vertical line
  if(fred.xcor()>0):
    
    run=False
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).